# How do I output this JSON value where the key starts with a number?

Tags: php, json

Take this json response:

```
    {
   "self":"http://macpro.local:2990/jira/rest/api/2/issue/CSS-4/votes",
   "votes":2,
   "hasVoted":true,
   "voters":[
      {
         "self":"http://macpro.local:2990/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=admin",
         "name":"admin",
         "avatarUrls":{
            "16x16":"http://macpro.local:2990/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10062",
            "48x48":"http://macpro.local:2990/jira/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10062"
         },
         "displayName":"admin",
         "active":true
      },
      {
         "self":"http://macpro.local:2990/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=timn_1",
         "name":"timn_1",
         "avatarUrls":{
            "16x16":"http://macpro.local:2990/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10062",
            "48x48":"http://macpro.local:2990/jira/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10062"
         },
         "displayName":"User Two",
         "active":true
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm at a loss for how to get the avatarUrls->16x16 from above. I've been getting everything else pretty easily with commands like:

```
$decoded = json_decode($result);
$decoded->votes; //returns # of votes
$decoded->voters->name; //returns the name
```

But how do I get the 16x16 value? I get an error if I try this:

```
$decoded->voters->avatarUrls->16x16;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as always.

```
$decoded->voters->avatarUrls->{'16x16'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do

```
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);
$decoded['voters']['avatarUrls']['16x16'];
```

if you like the Array style better.