# Parse JSON response where the object starts with a number in c#

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest, portable-class-library

I'm trying to deserialise a response from a REST service into C# Strongly typed classes - however I've ran into the same issue has in this post: 
[How do I output this JSON value where the key starts with a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522199/how-do-i-output-this-json-value-where-the-key-starts-with-a-number)

However I have the issue that you cannot start a variable name in c# with a number - meaning that the class at that level just deserialises into null.

I need to know how to get into the objects and deserialise them into the c# classes.

My Current code is below:

```
public static async Task<T> MakeAPIGetRequest<T>(string uri)
    {
        Uri requestURI = new Uri(uri);
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await client.GetAsync(requestURI);
            if (responseGet.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format(
                "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                responseGet.StatusCode,
                responseGet.Content));
            }
            else
            { 
            string response = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                T objects = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response));

                return objects;
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I cannot change the way the service is pushing the data back

Comment: post the sample json.

Comment: I think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218536/deserialize-json-that-has-some-property-name-starting-with-a-number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize json that has some property name starting with a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218536/deserialize-json-that-has-some-property-name-starting-with-a-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to deal with this was to use the JsonProperty tag on the target classes to define what Json property to listen for, as shown below (referenced from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218536/deserialize-json-that-has-some-property-name-starting-with-a-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522199/how-do-i-output-this-json-value-where-the-key-starts-with-a-number)

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "24hhigh")]
    public string Highest { get; set; }
    ...
```

Thanks to @HebeleHododo for the comment answer

Comment: how are you gonna do it for `[{'1':{'name':'test','age':'test'}},{'2':{'name':'another','age':'another'}}]`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh you would put "1" in the property name, or if its a variable amount of items you would use a for loop using your method.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no direct way to construct a strongly typed C# object in this case, You could still have the capabilities to parse the `json` string manually and extract values -

```
var json = "{'1':{'name':'test','age':'test'}}";
var t = JObject.Parse(json)["1"];
Console.WriteLine(t["name"]); //test
Console.WriteLine(t["age"]);  //test
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - this was how i was going to approach it until i saw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218536/deserialize-json-that-has-some-property-name-starting-with-a-number which makes it possible.